# Recycler View in Drawer Layout

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I create a default Drawer Layout from latest Android Studio. I want to put some picture and names on firebase and retrieve it from firebase and show pictures with their names in my recycler view on home fragment. I successfully store data and retrieve it but whene i set it on recycler view my app is crashed. I provide all layouts and java files i edited. Plese help me. How can i get rid of this crash and put data on my recycler view.

**HomeFragment.java**  , Here i think its crashes when i use this recyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter) line.

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    private HomeViewModel homeViewModel;

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    MyAdapter myAdapter;
    List<Upload> uploadList;
    DatabaseReference databaseReference;

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {



        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        recyclerView = root.findViewById(R.id.recyclerviewid);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
        uploadList = new ArrayList<>();
        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Upload");
        databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                for(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 :dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                {
                    Upload upload = dataSnapshot1.getValue(Upload.class);
                    uploadList.add(upload);
                }
                myAdapter = new MyAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),uploadList);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter);

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Error "+ databaseError.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });
        return root;
    }
}
```

**HomeViewModel.java**

```
public class HomeViewModel extends ViewModel {

    private MutableLiveData<String> mText;

    public HomeViewModel() {
        mText = new MutableLiveData<>();
        mText.setValue("This is home fragment");
    }

    public LiveData<String> getText() {
        return mText;
    }
}
```

**MainActivity.java** i don't edit this after creating Default Drawer layout

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private AppBarConfiguration mAppBarConfiguration;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_gallery, R.id.nav_slideshow)
                .setDrawerLayout(drawer)
                .build();
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, mAppBarConfiguration)
                || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
    }

    public void goAdmin(MenuItem item) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

** MyAdapter.java**

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    public Context context;
    public List<Upload> uploadlist;
    ViewGroup viewGroup;
    MyViewHolder myViewHolder;

    public MyAdapter(Context context, List<Upload> uploadimge) {
        this.context = context;
        this.uploadlist = uploadimge;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.listview, parent, false);

        return new MyViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Upload upload= uploadlist.get(position);
        myViewHolder.textView.setText(upload.imageName);
        Picasso.with(context).load(upload.uri).fit().centerCrop().into(myViewHolder.imageView);

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {

        return uploadlist.size();
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public  TextView textView;
        public  ImageView imageView;
        public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            textView =(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardtvid);
            imageView =(ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardimgid);

        }
    }
}
```

**Upload.java**

```
public class Upload {
    public String imageName;
    public String uri;


    public Upload()
    {

    }

    public Upload(String  s1,String s2)
    {
        this.imageName=s1;
        this.uri=s2;
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**fragment_home.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.home.HomeFragment">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/recyclerviewid" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**LogCat**

```
03-17 16:17:54.657 17920-17920/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
03-17 16:17:54.721 17920-17931/? I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 6421(305KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 33% free, 3MB/5MB, paused 10.119ms total 31.195ms
03-17 16:17:54.721 17920-17929/? I/System: FinalizerDaemon: finalize objects = 1
03-17 16:17:54.964 17920-17920/com.example.islamicproducts W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.islamicproducts-1/lib/arm
03-17 16:17:56.176 17920-17962/com.example.islamicproducts D/OpenSSLLib: OpensslErr:Module:12(116:176); file:external/boringssl/src/crypto/asn1/asn1_lib.c ;Line:186;Function:ASN1_get_object
03-17 16:17:56.405 17920-17931/com.example.islamicproducts I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 5923(588KB) AllocSpace objects, 4(80KB) LOS objects, 24% free, 4MB/6MB, paused 674us total 190.059ms
03-17 16:17:56.407 17920-17920/com.example.islamicproducts W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter androidx.vectordrawable.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
03-17 16:17:56.714 17920-17920/com.example.islamicproducts I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<androidx.core.view.ViewCompat$2>
03-17 16:17:56.715 17920-17920/com.example.islamicproducts I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<androidx.core.view.ViewCompat$2>
03-17 16:17:57.898 17920-17920/com.example.islamicproducts D/OpenGLRenderer: Dumper init 2 threads <0xb97cc948>
03-17 16:17:57.899 17920-17920/com.example.islamicproducts D/OpenGLRenderer: <com.example.islamicproducts> is running.
03-17 16:17:57.902 17920-18015/com.example.islamicproducts D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: false
03-17 16:17:57.902 17920-18015/com.example.islamicproducts D/OpenGLRenderer: CanvasContext() 0xb97cda58
03-17 16:17:58.129 17920-17931/com.example.islamicproducts W/art: Suspending all threads took: 21.357ms
03-17 16:17:58.217 17920-17931/com.example.islamicproducts I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 6564(706KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 12% free, 5MB/6MB, paused 99.131ms total 187.979ms
03-17 16:17:58.267 17920-18018/com.example.islamicproducts D/libc-netbsd: [getaddrinfo]: hostname=islamicproducts-51994.firebaseio.com; servname=(null); netid=0; mark=0
03-17 16:17:58.267 17920-18018/com.example.islamicproducts D/libc-netbsd: [getaddrinfo]: ai_addrlen=0; ai_canonname=(null); ai_flags=4; ai_family=0
03-17 16:17:58.274 17920-18018/com.example.islamicproducts D/libc-netbsd: [getaddrinfo]: hostname=islamicproducts-51994.firebaseio.com; servname=(null); netid=0; mark=0
03-17 16:17:58.274 17920-18018/com.example.islamicproducts D/libc-netbsd: [getaddrinfo]: ai_addrlen=0; ai_canonname=(null); ai_flags=1024; ai_family=0
03-17 16:17:58.382 17920-18015/com.example.islamicproducts D/OpenGLRenderer: CanvasContext() 0xb97cda58 initialize window=0xb97678e8, title=com.example.islamicproducts/com.example.islamicproducts.MainActivity
03-17 16:17:58.382 17920-17920/com.example.islamicproducts D/Surface: Surface::allocateBuffers(this=0xb97678e0)
03-17 16:17:58.464 17920-18015/com.example.islamicproducts I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
03-17 16:17:58.465 17920-18015/com.example.islamicproducts D/OpenGLRenderer: Created EGL context (0xb8832830)
03-17 16:17:58.475 17920-18015/com.example.islamicproducts I/OpenGLRenderer: Get enable program binary service property (1)
03-17 16:17:58.475 17920-18015/com.example.islamicproducts I/OpenGLRenderer: Initializing program atlas...
03-17 16:17:58.476 17920-18015/com.example.islamicproducts D/ProgramBinary/Service: BpProgramBinaryService.getFileDescriptor
03-17 16:17:58.518 17920-18015/com.example.islamicproducts D/ProgramBinary/Service: BpProgramBinaryService.getProgramMapLen
03-17 16:17:58.518 17920-18015/com.example.islamicproducts D/ProgramBinary/Service: BpProgramBinaryService.getProgramMapArray
03-17 16:17:58.520 17920-18015/com.example.islamicproducts D/ProgramBinary/Service: BpProgramBinaryService.getProgramBinaryLen
03-17 16:17:58.521 17920-18015/com.example.islamicproducts I/OpenGLRenderer: Program binary detail: Binary length is 111796, program map length is 152.
03-17 16:17:58.521 17920-18015/com.example.islamicproducts I/OpenGLRenderer: Succeeded to mmap program binaries. File descriptor is 35, and path is /dev/ashmem�}Hնh0˵�ۓ�.
03-17 16:17:58.521 17920-18015/com.example.islamicproducts I/OpenGLRenderer: No need to use file discriptor anymore, close fd(35).
03-17 16:17:58.533 17920-18015/com.example.islamicproducts D/OpenGLRenderer: Initializing program cache from 0xb6d83090, size = 9
03-17 16:17:58.548 17920-18015/com.example.islamicproducts D/OpenGLRenderer: -- init (key = 0x0000000000000000)
03-17 16:17:58.549 17920-18015/com.example.islamicproducts D/OpenGLRenderer: -- init (key = 0x0000000000000001)
03-17 16:17:58.550 17920-18015/com.example.islamicproducts D/OpenGLRenderer: -- init (key = 0x0000000000500041)
03-17 16:17:58.550 17920-18015/com.example.islamicproducts D/OpenGLRenderer: -- init (key = 0x0000000800000003)
03-17 16:17:58.551 17920-18015/com.example.islamicproducts D/OpenGLRenderer: -- init (key = 0x0000001000000000)
03-17 16:17:58.551 17920-18015/com.example.islamicproducts D/OpenGLRenderer: -- init (key = 0x0000001000000008)
03-17 16:17:58.552 17920-18015/com.example.islamicproducts D/OpenGLRenderer: -- init (key = 0x0000001000500040)
03-17 16:17:58.553 17920-18015/com.example.islamicproducts D/OpenGLRenderer: -- init (key = 0x0000001800000000)
03-17 16:17:58.553 17920-18015/com.example.islamicproducts D/OpenGLRenderer: -- init (key = 0x0000003800000000)
03-17 16:17:58.554 17920-18015/com.example.islamicproducts D/Surface: Surface::connect(this=0xb97678e0,api=1)
03-17 16:17:58.555 17920-18015/com.example.islamicproducts W/libEGL: [ANDROID_RECORDABLE] format: 1
03-17 16:17:58.565 17920-18015/com.example.islamicproducts D/Surface: Surface::setBufferCount(this=0xb97678e0,bufferCount=4)
03-17 16:17:58.654 17920-18015/com.example.islamicproducts D/GraphicBuffer: register, handle(0xb9801250) (w:480 h:800 s:480 f:0x1 u:0x000f02)
03-17 16:17:58.862 17920-18015/com.example.islamicproducts D/OpenGLRenderer: CacheTexture 3 upload: x, y, width height = 0, 0, 512, 39
03-17 16:17:58.917 17920-18015/com.example.islamicproducts D/OpenGLRenderer: ProgramCache save to disk, size = 9
03-17 16:17:58.965 17920-17931/com.example.islamicproducts I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 3954(351KB) AllocSpace objects, 4(80KB) LOS objects, 9% free, 5MB/6MB, paused 25.002ms total 101.198ms
03-17 16:17:58.974 17920-18015/com.example.islamicproducts D/GraphicBuffer: register, handle(0xb9848ac0) (w:480 h:800 s:480 f:0x1 u:0x000f02)
03-17 16:17:59.285 17920-18018/com.example.islamicproducts D/libc-netbsd: getaddrinfo: islamicproducts-51994.firebaseio.com get result from proxy gai_error = 0
03-17 16:17:59.286 17920-18018/com.example.islamicproducts D/Posix: [Posix_connect Debug]Process com.example.islamicproducts :443 
03-17 16:17:59.884 17920-18018/com.example.islamicproducts D/libc-netbsd: [getaddrinfo]: hostname=islamicproducts-51994.firebaseio.com; servname=(null); netid=0; mark=0
03-17 16:17:59.884 17920-18018/com.example.islamicproducts D/libc-netbsd: [getaddrinfo]: ai_addrlen=0; ai_canonname=(null); ai_flags=4; ai_family=0
03-17 16:17:59.885 17920-18018/com.example.islamicproducts D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0xb9835668 NativeCrypto_SSL_do_handshake fd=0xa10c4390 shc=0xa10c4394 timeout_millis=60000 client_mode=1 npn=0x0
03-17 16:17:59.885 17920-18018/com.example.islamicproducts D/NativeCrypto: doing handshake ++
03-17 16:17:59.885 17920-18018/com.example.islamicproducts D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0xb9835668 handshake start in CINIT  before connect initialization
03-17 16:17:59.885 17920-18018/com.example.islamicproducts D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0xb9835668 info_callback calling handshakeCompleted
03-17 16:17:59.885 17920-18018/com.example.islamicproducts D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0xb9835668 info_callback completed
03-17 16:17:59.886 17920-18018/com.example.islamicproducts D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0xb9835668 SSL_connect:error exit in 3RSH_A SSLv3 read server hello A
03-17 16:17:59.886 17920-18018/com.example.islamicproducts D/NativeCrypto: doing handshake -- ret=-1
03-17 16:17:59.886 17920-18018/com.example.islamicproducts D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0xb9835668 NativeCrypto_SSL_do_handshake ret=-1 errno=11 sslError=2 timeout_millis=60000
03-17 16:18:01.987 17920-18018/com.example.islamicproducts D/NativeCrypto: doing handshake ++
03-17 16:18:01.992 17920-18018/com.example.islamicproducts D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0xb9835668 SSL_connect:error exit in 3RSC_A SSLv3 read server certificate A
03-17 16:18:01.993 17920-18018/com.example.islamicproducts D/NativeCrypto: doing handshake -- ret=-1
03-17 16:18:01.993 17920-18018/com.example.islamicproducts D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0xb9835668 NativeCrypto_SSL_do_handshake ret=-1 errno=11 sslError=2 timeout_millis=60000
03-17 16:18:01.993 17920-18018/com.example.islamicproducts D/NativeCrypto: doing handshake ++
03-17 16:18:02.001 17920-18018/com.example.islamicproducts E/NativeCrypto: ssl=0xb9835668 cert_verify_callback x509_store_ctx=0xa10c41bc arg=0x0
03-17 16:18:02.001 17920-18018/com.example.islamicproducts E/NativeCrypto: ssl=0xb9835668 cert_verify_callback calling verifyCertificateChain authMethod=ECDHE_RSA
03-17 16:18:02.124 17920-18018/com.example.islamicproducts D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0xb9835668 cert_verify_callback => 1
03-17 16:18:02.149 17920-18018/com.example.islamicproducts D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0xb9835668 SSL_connect:error exit in 3RFINA SSLv3 read finished A
03-17 16:18:02.149 17920-18018/com.example.islamicproducts D/NativeCrypto: doing handshake -- ret=-1
03-17 16:18:02.149 17920-18018/com.example.islamicproducts D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0xb9835668 NativeCrypto_SSL_do_handshake ret=-1 errno=11 sslError=2 timeout_millis=60000
03-17 16:18:02.463 17920-18018/com.example.islamicproducts D/NativeCrypto: doing handshake ++
03-17 16:18:02.463 17920-18018/com.example.islamicproducts D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0xb9835668 handshake done in SSLOK  SSL negotiation finished successfully
03-17 16:18:02.463 17920-18018/com.example.islamicproducts D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0xb9835668 info_callback calling handshakeCompleted
03-17 16:18:02.464 17920-18018/com.example.islamicproducts D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0xb9835668 info_callback completed
03-17 16:18:02.464 17920-18018/com.example.islamicproducts D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0xb9835668 SSL_connect:ok exit in SSLOK  SSL negotiation finished successfully
03-17 16:18:02.464 17920-18018/com.example.islamicproducts D/NativeCrypto: doing handshake -- ret=1
03-17 16:18:02.464 17920-18018/com.example.islamicproducts D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0xb9835668 NativeCrypto_SSL_get_certificate => NULL
```

Comment: share the logcat

Comment: please see .. i share my LogCat

Comment: sorry i couldn't get much information from logcat , you said the error is in setAdapter line but the logcat is not pointing to any of your code, sorry

Comment: Yes I toast a massage before this line and database data as a text and show well.

Comment: is that toast message in the code above

Comment: no, I remove it , this toast in the for each loop

Comment: I solved my issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. In **HomeFragment.java** change this two line. Just use **root.getContetx()** for context.

```
 myAdapter = new MyAdapter(root.getContext(),uploadList);
                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(root.getContext()));
```

2. In **MyAdapter.java** replace viewGroup by holder in **onBindViewHolder** mathod

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Upload upload= uploadlist.get(position);
        holder.textView.setText(upload.imageName);
        Picasso.with(context).load(upload.uri).placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).fit().centerCrop().into(holder.imageView);

    }
```